# Navigation bar with "Prefers Large Titles" and embedded PageViewController not collapsing

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

I have setup a "UIViewController" (Embedded in "UINavigationController"), and the "UIViewController" has a "ContainerView" with a "UIPageViewController".

In the "UIPageViewController" are few subviews with "UITableViews".

The problem is now, the "UINavigationBar" with enabled "Prefer Large Titles" are not collapsing if the TableView (Embedded in ContainerView) scrolls.

I think that's a problem with the "UIPageViewController". The size is the same as the ContainerView.

How can I fix this issue ?

[image: See Screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703469/shrink-large-title-when-scrolling-not-uitableviewcontroller-ios-11

Comment: https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment/issues/210

Answer (score 3):

Auto-collapsing large title bars are only active if the "root" view of the controller is a tableview or a scrollview.

Since your tableviews are embedded in a containerView, the title bar has no knowledge of what's going on inside that containerView.

Offhand, I'd say you would have to use a delegate / protocol pattern to have your embedded tableview (controller) tell the containerView containing view controller to change the size of the title bar.

Comment: I understand. Do you think it is possible to use the "ContainerView" into a "UIScrollView" for this issue ?

Comment: If you replace ContainerView with a ScrollView, and then try to add a PageViewController (that uses table views) as a subview of the scroll view, I expect you'll have additional navigation issues and conflicting scroll action issues. Tough to say without understanding your full UI / flow.