# Large title doesn't collapse in UIPageViewController with scroll transition style

Tags: swift, scroll, uipageviewcontroller, navigationbar, preferslargetitles

I have a `UIPageViewController` that holds an array of `UITableViewController`. I did set `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`.

When I scroll the table to the top, the title of the `UIPageViewController` doesn't collapse to the navigation bar if the `TransitionStyle` is `.scroll`.
If instead I set the transition to `.pageCurl` it works fine.

I need the title to scroll with the table like in a normal `UITableViewControl`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation bar with "Prefers Large Titles" and embedded PageViewController not collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540262/navigation-bar-with-prefers-large-titles-and-embedded-pageviewcontroller-not-c)